# How can I make a loop in R that produces these matrices?

Tags: r, loops, optimization, linear-programming, gurobi

I am trying to solve large scale assignment problems with Gurobi in R. I need a loop that will produce the constraint matrices for any n I specify since I will not be able to manually enter them for very large problems. I pasted sample matrices for n=2 and n=3 and also the code I have come up with for n=2. I need the n-i part to continue as 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. but each new row needs to be cumulative. I know I have a long way to go and I am very new to R. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
n=2

1 1 0 0 
0 0 1 1 
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1

n=3
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1



library("gurobi")

model <- list()

n=2

i=0
while (i <= n-2) {
  print(i)
  i = i+1
}
i

a=rep(1,n) 
b=rep(0,(n-i)*n)
c=rep(0,n) 
d=rep(1,n) 
e=rep(0,(n-i)*n)
f=rep(1:0, times=n)
g=rep(0:1, times=n)



model$A          <- matrix(c(a,b,c,d,e,f,g), nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow=T)
model$obj        <- c(1,2,3,4)
model$modelsense <- "min"
model$rhs        <- c(1,1,1,1)
model$sense      <- c('=', '=','=','=')
model$vtype      <- 'B'

params <- list(OutputFlag=0)

result <- gurobi(model, params)

print('Solution:')
print(result$objval)
print(result$x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use kronecker products as shown:

```
make_mat <- function(k) {
  d <- diag(k)
  ones <- t(rep(1, k))
  rbind( d %x% ones, ones %x% d )
}
lapply(2:3, make_mat)
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    0
[2,]    0    0    1    1
[3,]    1    0    1    0
[4,]    0    1    0    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1
[4,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0
[5,]    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
[6,]    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1
```